# Binomial identity in Riordan's Combinatorial Identities

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am reading Riordan's *Combinatorial Identities*. On page 8 there is a formula like screenshot. I have no problem to understand the first three lines, in which we use $(-1)^m \cdot \binom{-n}{m} = \binom{n + m - 1 }{m}$ twice and [Vandemonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) in between. I could not understand the last step.

[image: riordan_page8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note:* It is helpful to use indices with lower and upper limit to clarify aspects of this kind.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\binom{n-p}{m}}&=(-1)^m\binom{p-n+m-1}{m}\tag{1}\\
> &=(-1)^m\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{p}{m-k}\binom{-n+m-1}{k}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{p}{m-k}\binom{n-m+k}{k}(-1)^{m+k}\tag{3}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{p}{k}\binom{n-k}{m-k}(-1)^k}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows according to your analysis and as indicated in the comment below.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{-p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (2) we apply [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)*.
- In (3) we use again the binomial identity from (1).
- In (4) we shift the index $k\to m-k$.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck for a while then I realize I can just replace $m-k$ with $u$ and last step comes naturally from the previous step:

$$
\binom{p}{u} \cdot \binom{n-u}{m-u}
$$

The power of $-1$ becomes $(-1)^{u+2k} = (-1)^u$. Eventually rename $u$ with dummy variable $k$.